# RFC 2812 message validation regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, reinventing-the-wheel, chat

In my ongoing quest for an IRC client, I'm working on more stringent validation per [RFC 2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#page-6).  As with everything else I'm doing on this project, I'm trying to implement it all from scratch for the sake of joy/frustration and education.  Thus I'm not going to be using any other libraries or tools designed to work with IRC clients/servers/messages/etc.

I've written this regex to validate a message.  It's a little hairy, so I'm wondering if there's a way to reduce repetition, or at least to make it cleaner and easier to read.  I didn't always add comments when I felt a section was easy to read, or if it was identical to another one I had previously commented.

I've also thought about maybe splitting it up into the different sections of prefix, command, and parameters, and then validating each separately.

Alternately, do you think that ditching regexes entirely might be a better solution?  Right now I do consider this readable and maintainable, albeit with some effort, but I'd like to know if you feel the same.

```
import re

message_regex = re.compile(
    r"""
    # Validation of RFC 2812 messages
    # https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#page-6
    ^       # Match from the start
    # Optional prefix
    (   # leading colon required
        :(?P<prefix>     
            # prefix group can be the server's name, which consists of
            (?P<server_name>
                [a-zA-Z0-9]     # A leading alphanumeric character
                [a-zA-Z0-9\-]*  # Followed by the same with hyphens
                [a-zA-Z0-9]*    # Can't have the final character be a hyphen
                # Then the above with a leading period
                (\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*
            ) | # otherwise it can be a nickname
            (?P<nickname>
                [a-zA-Z\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7D]          # letter or special character 
                [a-zA-Z0-9\x5B-\x60\x7B-\x7D\-]{,8} # up to 8 of the same, plus digits/hyphens
                # followed by an optional host, which in turn has an optional user
                (
                    # Any octet but NULL, CR, LF, space, or at-sign
                    (!(?P<user>[^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x40]{1,}))?
                    @(?P<host> # The host has a leading at sign
                        # Either a server name
                        (?P<hostname>
                            [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*
                            (\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*
                        )|
                        # Or a host address
                        (?P<hostaddr>
                            (?P<ip4address> (\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) |
                            (?P<ip6address>
                                # Either a hex sequence followed by 7
                                # more colon-separated hex sequences
                                ([a-fA-F0-9]{1,}(:[a-fA-F0-9]{1,}){7})| 
                                # Or this thing followed by an ip4 address
                                0:0:0:0:0:(0|FFFF):(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )?
            )
        )
        [ ]       # trailing space
    )?
    # Then a command
    (?P<command>[a-zA-Z]{1,}|\d{3})
    # Then optional parameters
    (?P<parameters>
        ( 
            # space followed by non-null, crlf, space, colon up to 14 times
            (
                [ ][^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A]
                # Then a colon or the same as above, minus the space
                (:|[^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A])*
            ){,14}
            # then the last element, which is the above but clumped into one
            ([ ]:(:|[ ]|[^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A])*)?
        )|
        (
            # identical to above, except exactly 14 of the first, then
            # the first of the last-segment's colons is optional
            ([ ][^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A](:|[^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A])*){14}
            ([ ]:?(:|[ ]|[^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A])*)?
        )
    )
    # Then a newline
    \r\n
    $       # to the end
    """
    , re.VERBOSE)
```

Here are some sample messages:

```
:Macha!~macha@unaffiliated/macha PRIVMSG #botwar :Test response
USER username 0 * :Real name
PING :message
:source JOIN :#channel
:source PART #channel :reason
:source QUIT :reason
```

Comment: @Phrancis is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, it is better. Just understand it is highly unusual for someone to ask for a code review of a regular expression pattern... Even the Python tags here are somewhat superfluous, since there is no Python code other than that which is needed to support the pattern...

Comment: Would it be possible to include a few sample *messages* that you're parsing?

Comment: @Mat'sMug sure. I'm out and about right now, but I'll try and get to that in a few hours.

Comment: should ` (?<parameters>` be ` (?P<parameters>` ?

Comment: here it is in a regex fiddle to play with: https://regex101.com/r/wY4oV4/1

Comment: @rbp fixed. sorry, that was my bad, I copy-pasted from the wrong window

Comment: You tagged this question as [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]. What is the antecedent that you are reinventing?

Comment: @200_success in this case rfc2812 message validation. There are libraries and applications existing that solve this problem, as well as of irc clients in general

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're interested in matching byte strings here (not Unicode strings), and so to make this clear (and for compatibility with Python 3) I recommend adding the `b` prefix to the regular expression.
2. I don't think there's anywhere where you care about the difference between `a` and `A` (you're always matching case-insensitively). So you could pass the [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) flag and use `[A-Z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`, which would shorten things.
3. There's no need to escape a hyphen in a character class if it's the first or last character in the class. Also, `\d` matches a digit in a character class. So `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]` can become `[a-zA-Z\d-]`, or `[A-Z\d-]` if you use `re.IGNORECASE`.
4. `{1,}` can be written as `+`.
5. This part of the regular expression doesn't prevent the final character from being a hyphen:

   ```
    [a-zA-Z0-9]     # A leading alphanumeric character
    [a-zA-Z0-9\-]*  # Followed by the same with hyphens
    [a-zA-Z0-9]*    # Can't have the final character be a hyphen
   ```

That's because `*` means "zero or more times" and so the `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` might match zero times.

I can see that you are just following the syntax in [RFC 2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#page-6), but that's a mistake! If you look at [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) then you'll see the syntax for hostnames was originally given as follows:

```
    <hname> ::= <name>*["."<name>]
    <name> ::= <let>[*[<let-or-digit-or-hyphen>]<let-or-digit>]
```

and then in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-13) "the restriction on the first character is relaxed to allow either a letter or a digit". So this corresponds to:

```
    [A-Z\d]        # A leading alphanumeric character
    (?:
       [A-Z\d-]*   # Optionally followed by the same with hyphens
       [A-Z\d]     # But the final character must not be a hyphen
    )?
```

1. This part of the regular expression:

   ```
    [a-zA-Z0-9\-]*
    [a-zA-Z0-9]*
   ```

can match the same string in multiple ways, which is unwise for performance reasons. The problem is that when a string fails to match, the regular expression engine will have to backtrack many times before it can prove that there is no match.

For example, it takes half a millisecond for Python to determine that the regular expression `A*Z` fails to match a string of 100,000 letter ‘A’s:

```
    >>> timeit(lambda:re.match('A*Z', 'A'*100000), number=1)
    0.0005234569543972611
```

but it takes nearly 14 seconds (more than 26,000 times as long) to determine that `A*A*Z` fails to match this string:

```
    >>> timeit(lambda:re.match('A*A*Z', 'A'*100000), number=1)
    13.715154931996949
```

So what you need here is:

```
    [A-Z\d]+         # Initial alphanumeric word.
    (?:-+[A-Z\d]+)*  # Hyphen(s) followed by word, zero or more times.
```

1. `(:|[^\x00\x0A\x0D\x20\x3A])` is a long-winded way of writing `[^\x00\n\r ]`.
2. There are a lot of unused capturing parentheses. For example, in

   ```
    ([a-fA-F0-9]{1,}(:[a-fA-F0-9]{1,}){7})|
    0:0:0:0:0:(0|FFFF):(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
   ```

there are four capturing parentheses. These can either be omitted if unnecessary, or changed to be non-capturing:

```
    [a-fA-F\d]+(?::a-fA-F\d]+){7}|
    0:0:0:0:0:(?:0|FFFF):(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

1. If you're worried about the readability of this giant regular expression, consider building it out of named parts using string formatting. This allows you to avoid some of the repetition by reusing parts. For example, you might start like this:

   ```
    def build_message_regexp():
        word = rb'[A-Z\d]+'
        shortname = rb'{word}(?:-+{word})*'.format(**locals())
        hostname = rb'{shortname}(?:\.{shortname})*'.format(**locals())
        ip4addr = rb'\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}'
        hexdigit = rb'[A-F\d]'
        ip6addr1 = rb'{hexdigit}+(?::{hexdigit}+){7}|'.format(**locals())
        ip6addr2 = rb'0:0:0:0:0:(?:0|FFFF):{ip4addr}'.format(**locals())
   ```